# Create table from CSV with values containing commas enclosed in quotes

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I'm trying to create a table in Impala from a CSV that I've uploaded into an HDFS directory.  The CSV contains values with commas enclosed inside quotes.

Example:

```
1.66.96.0/19,"NTT Docomo,INC.","Ntt Docomo",9605,"NTT DOCOMO, INC."
1.66.128.0/17,"NTT Docomo,INC.","Ntt Docomo",9605,"NTT DOCOMO, INC."
1.67.0.0/17,"NTT Docomo,INC.","Ntt Docomo",9605,"NTT DOCOMO, INC."
1.67.128.0/18,"NTT Docomo,INC.","Ntt Docomo",9605,"NTT DOCOMO, INC."
1.67.192.0/19,"NTT Docomo,INC.","Ntt Docomo",9605,"NTT DOCOMO, INC."
```

The [Impala documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/1-x/1-1-1/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_txtfile.html) says that this can be solved with an `ESCAPED BY` clause.  Here's my current code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

CREATE TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4 (
  network STRING
 ,isp STRING
 ,organization STRING
 ,autonomous_system_number STRING
 ,autonomous_system_organization STRING
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'

LOCATION 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/';

INVALIDATE METADATA GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/' 
INTO TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;
```

I've also tried using the `ESCAPED BY '"'` clause.  In both cases, Impala takes the comma within the quotes and uses it as a delimiter, splitting the value into two columns.

Any ideas on how to fix the code so that this won't happen?

**EDIT (6/9/2015)**

So, I've gone through the following variations, based on suggestions from @K S Nidhin and @JTUP.  However, each variation returned the same result as the queries written without the `SERDEPROPERTIES` operator, with the commas still causing values to appear in the wrong columns:

*Variation 1*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

CREATE TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4 (
  network STRING
 ,isp STRING
 ,organization STRING
 ,autonomous_system_number STRING
 ,autonomous_system_organization STRING
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "quoteChar" = "'", "escapeChar" = "\\" ) 

LOCATION 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/';

INVALIDATE METADATA GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/' 
INTO TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;
```

*Variation 2*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

CREATE TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4 (
  network STRING
 ,isp STRING
 ,organization STRING
 ,autonomous_system_number STRING
 ,autonomous_system_organization STRING
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'quoteChar' = '"', 'escapeChar' = '\\' )

LOCATION 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/';

INVALIDATE METADATA GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/' 
INTO TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;
```

*Variation 3*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

CREATE TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4 (
  network STRING
 ,isp STRING
 ,organization STRING
 ,autonomous_system_number STRING
 ,autonomous_system_organization STRING
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\,",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)

LOCATION 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/';

INVALIDATE METADATA GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/' 
INTO TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;
```

Any other ideas, or further variations of the `SERDEPROPERTIES` operator to try?

**EDIT (6/10/2016)**

I was able to get a different variation of the query using the `SERDE` and `SERDEPROPERTIES` operators to work in Hive (based on code provided in the [Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde)), with the proper table being created:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

CREATE TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4(network STRING
 ,isp STRING
 ,organization STRING
 ,autonomous_system_number STRING
 ,autonomous_system_organization STRING)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar'     = '"',
   'escapeChar'    = '\\'
)   
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/' 
INTO TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;
```

Since the `SERDE` operator isn't available in Impala, this solution wouldn't work there.  I'm fine creating the tables in Hive, but it's still irksome that I can't find a viable solution in Impala.

Comment: Try adding serde properties WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

CREATE TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4 (
  network STRING
 ,isp STRING
 ,organization STRING
 ,autonomous_system_number STRING
 ,autonomous_system_organization STRING
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'

WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\,",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)

LOCATION 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/';

INVALIDATE METADATA GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://.../GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4/' 
INTO TABLE GeoIP2_ISP_Blocks_IPv4;
```

Add with SERDEPROPERTIES which should hopefully do the trick

Comment: Just tried it.  Unfortunately it looks like `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` isn't supported by Impala.

Comment: made an edit check to see if it works. i haven't done this since my last job. so not sure if i have it in the right place. but with serdeproperties should help with the commas.

Answer (score 1):

what I did was to firstly convert the delimiter from comma to other character, e.g pipe ('|'). 
You can use csvformat(part of csvkit) on linux.

```
csvformat -D \| input_filename.csv > input_filename-pipe.csv
```

afterwards, set the delimiter to '|' in the impala query

```
 TERMINATED BY '|'
```